# Check if two arrays can be linked

Tags: arrays, groovy, combinations, permutation

I am working on a piece of component and kind of stuck and need some help on how to proceed. My problem is below:

I have 2 arrays of objects. Lets say arrays of persons. The person object has person id, parentId, and other fields as attributes.
Array 1 has only male and Array 2 has only female persons.

So, a sample would look something like this:

*Array 1:*
personId   sex    parentId
11    M   1
22    M   2
33    M   3

*Array 2:*
personId   sex    parentId
44      F     1
55      F     2
66      F     3

*Array 3*
personId   sex    parentId
44      F     4
55      F     4
66      F     5

I need to check and see if I can link all Male to a Female such a way that I am not linking the siblings (persons from the same parent) and I am linking all.

For the above example, with array 1 and array 2, the linking should be: 11->66, 22->44, 33->55. With array 1 and array 3, it would be 11->44, 22->55, 33->66 or any combination.

I hope I have clearly explained the problem on hand.

What I have worked out so far is below:

```
class Person {
    int id
    String sex
    String parentKey
}
class Pair {
    int id
    Person male
    Person female
}
class Sample {
    static main(args) {
        List<Person> males = [
            [1,'M','p1'],
            [2,'M','p2'],
            [3,'M','p3']
        ]
        List<Person> females = [
                    [4,'F','p1'],
                    [5,'F','p2'],
                    [6,'F','p3']
                ]
        List<Pair> pairs = checkIfCanBePaired(1,males,females)      
        for(Pair p : pairs) {
            println p
        }       
    }
    public static List<Pair> checkIfCanBePaired(int id, List<Person> males, List<Person> females) { 
        List<Pair> pairs = []
        boolean matchFound = false      
        for(int i=0; i < males.size() ; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j < females.size() ; j++) {
                Person m = males.get(i)
                Person f = females.get(j)
                if(m.parentKey != f.parentKey) {
                    matchFound = true
                    Pair p = new Pair(id++,m,f)
                    pairs.add(p)
                    males.remove(i)
                    females.remove(j)
                    pairs.addAll(checkIfCanBePaired(id,males,females))
                }
            }
        }
        return pairs
    }
}
```

The piece of code I have tried so far is above. Where I am stuck is, as per my above code, 1 gets linked to 5 and 2 gets linked to 4 which leaves 3 and 6 from the same parent. How do i get it working so that 1 and 6 gets linked?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I agree with @shmosel. I have an idea of what to do, but I don't want to just give you the answer, especially not in code? What have you tired so far? What are your thoughts to represent the problem?

Comment: Thanks @shmosel . The piece of code I have tried so far is above. Where I am stuck is, as per my above code, 1 gets linked to 5 and 2 gets linked to 4 which leaves 3 and 6 from the same parent. How do i get it working so that 1 and 6 gets linked?

Comment: In your original description you state 'I can link all Male to a Female' but your last comment seems to indicate you want to link all male to all females that aren't siblings, which is it? You are removing items from the arrays above so you're never going to match all to all, just the first one.

Comment: @MikeW Sorry for the confusion. I am not linking all male to a female. I want to link a male to a female. its a one-to-one mapping. Just assume there are 2 rooms. One with males and one with females. i just have to check and match up the male and female to form couples such a way that i get the maximum pairs. also, i should be cautious not matching up the siblings together. I hope it clears the confusion

Answer (score 0):

An array in Java can have only one data type. What you can use are parallel arrays where the index of an array will be mapped to the other parallel arrays

ex:

```
int [] personId = {11,22,33};
char [] sex = {'M', 'M', 'M'};
int [] parentId = {1,2,3};
```

by calling personId[0], sex[0] and parentId[0] you will be able to get the whole record.

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood the problem. It's not an array of primitive data type. Its an array of objects. I have updated the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution is below:**

```
class Person {
    int id
    String sex
    String parentKey
}
class Pair {
    int id
    Person male
    Person female
}
class Sample {
    static main(args) {
        List<Person> males = [
            [1,'M','p1'],
            [2,'M','p2'],
            [3,'M','p3'],
            [4,'M','p4'],
            [5,'M','p5']
        ]

        List<Person> females = [
                    [6,'F','p1'],
                    [7,'F','p2'],
                    [8,'F','p3'],
                    [9,'F','p4'],
                    [10,'F','p5']
                ]

        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for(int i=0 ; i < females.size() ; i++) {
            s.add(i)    
        }

        List<List<Integer>> permutations = permute(s.toArray(new Integer[0]))

        int index=0     
        boolean canBePaired = false

        while(index < permutations.size()) {
            females = shuffle(females, permutations.get(index))

            if(checkIfCanBePaired(males, females)) {
                canBePaired = true
                break
            }
            index++
        }

        if(canBePaired) {
            println "no. of tries="+(index+1)           
            List<Pair> pairs = pairThem(males, females)
            pairs.each {
                println it
            }
        } else {
            println "cages can't be paired"
        }
    }

    public static List<Person> shuffle(List<Person> person, List<Integer> order) {
        List<Person> reorderedPerson = []

        if(person.size()==order.size()) {
            for(int i=0 ; i<order.size();i++){
                reorderedPerson.add(person.get(order[i]))
            }
        }

        return reorderedPerson
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) {
            return results;
        }
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        dfs(nums, results, result);
        return results;
    }

    public static void dfs(int[] nums, List<List<Integer>> results, List<Integer> result) {
        if (nums.length == result.size()) {
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(result);
            results.add(temp);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            if (!result.contains(nums[i])) {
                result.add(nums[i]);
                dfs(nums, results, result);
                result.remove(result.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkIfCanBePaired(List<Person> males, List<Person> females) {
        int possiblePairs = 0

        if(males.size() <= females.size()) {
            possiblePairs  = males.size()
        } else {
            possiblePairs = females.size()
        }

        for(int i=0 ; i<possiblePairs ; i++) {  
            Person m = males.get(i)
            Person f = females.get(i)

            if(m.parentKey == f.parentKey) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    public static List<Pair> pairThem(List<Person> males, List<Person> females) {   
        List<Pair> pairs = []

        int possiblePairs = 0

        if(males.size() <= females.size()) {
            possiblePairs  = males.size()
        } else {
            possiblePairs = females.size()
        }

        println "no. of males="+males.size()
        println "no. of females="+females.size()
        println "males="+males
        println "females="+females
        println "no. of possible pairs="+possiblePairs

        int pairId = 1

        for(int i=0 ; i<possiblePairs ; i++) {
            pairs.add(new Pair(pairId++, (Person)males.get(i),(Person)females.get(i)))          
        }
        return pairs
    }

}
```